# NODEJS PHP - Can't start NODEJS Script from PHP EXEC

Tags: php, node.js

I have a NODE.JS Script which i can start manual at the Console with

```
cd /home/desktop/www/www.domain.com/bot/; 
node bot.js;
```

But when i want to do this with PHP EXEC it dont work - i tried over 2 days now with all solution on google but nothing helps.

```
$output = exec("cd /home/desktop/www/www.domain.com/bot/; node bot.js;");

print_r($output);
```

Output is always 1. There is also no error log or error message - nothing.

Regards

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Try to give a complete path. Make sure that the file path is correct.

```
$output = exec("node /home/desktop/www/www.domain.com/bot/bot.js;");
print_r($output);
```

Comment: I have tried this also - not working. No output. When i do it in the console manually it works perfect. Also EXEC commands which has no node works perfect. Only the node command doesnt work. I use NGINX - PHP5.6-FPM

Comment: What is the extpected output?

Comment: The script buys Crypto with. It works perfect manually i don't know why there is no output with EXEC.

Comment: Can you paste the complete content in the php file?

Comment: import ethers from 'ethers';
       ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)

Comment: When i run it in console everything works perfect

Answer (score 0):

PHP exec in windows uses CMD.exe by default.
So any command must observe cmd syntax.

`exec("cd /home/desktop/www/www.domain.com/bot/; node bot.js;");`

to
`exec("cd /home/desktop/www/www.domain.com/bot && node bot.js;");`

Of course assuming that `node` is available on the path

Comment: The problem ist - it dont work - there is no output on PHP. Can it be that there is a problem with php5.6-fpm and this?

Comment: I got same problem! Did you got it already?